# Create AWS CognitoUserPool in an Angular 4 application

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, typescript, aws-sdk

I need an AWS authentication in my angular application. So, I added the library files:

```
<script src="assets/vendor/jsbn.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/jsbn2.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/sjcl.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/aws-sdk.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/aws-cognito-sdk.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendor/amazon-cognito-identity.min.js"></script>
```

And imported the sdk in my typescript file:

```
import AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('aws-sdk');
```

Now, I need to create a userPool. I tried this:

```
 private poolData = {
    UserPoolId: "my-pool-id",
    ClientId: "my-client-id"
};

private userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(this.poolData);
```

But I got the error

> TypeError: AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool is not a constructor

I did everything that is described [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js) for using typescript.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Does either of these work?**

```
var AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');
import * as AmazonCognitoIdentity from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js).

---

**Other steps I had to do**

I had to do this in my Angular 6 app:

```
npm i amazon-cognito-identity-js
```

I was getting this error:

```
global is not defined
```

[I had add to polyfill.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9920#issuecomment-393424161):

```
(window as any).global = window;
```

---

Usually people do this for `'aws-sdk'`:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's a bit late for me, but maybe it will help others :)